# Removing a specific XML node in TIBCO BusinessWorks

Tags: xml, tibco

I have a "global variable" XML schema in TIBCO BusinessWorks. It's simpler than it looks - basically just a single repeatable node.

Image: Tibco globals.
(old URL redacted)

Various processes in the system can update this list. Checking to see if they are listed is easy:

> $GetVariable/subscriber-list/subscriber
>   = $_processContext/ns:ProcessContext/ProcessId

Adding themselves to the list is pretty easy too, using a Set Variable activity (see bottom half of image)

But how can a process remove itself from the list? I'm sure there's a type of mapping I can use to filter out the node I want and let the rest through?

Answer (score 1):

I can't access the image, so it's hard to know exactly, but the mapper into Set Variable should be something like:

```
$GetVariable[subscriber-list/subscriber != $_processContext/ns:ProcessContext/ProcessId]
```

If that's not it, just update the image link and I'll take another look.